# Automated FTP to upload new files to web server?

Tags: file, upload, ftp

I'm looking for a FTP client that I can use to upload new files from a local development machine to a remote web-server. I only want to upload the newly edited files though.

Is there a command line utility that can do this, that I can add into an automated process? Is there a GUI client available that can do this? Would be nice to have it cross-platform too. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 'backup' program called SyncBack that does this.

You can find out more about it here: http://www.2brightsparks.com

Answer (score 1):

The [Mercurial FTP Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FTPExtension) should do this for you, although I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Schedule a frequent synchronization of a local folder against a remote folder (or moving all files from local folder to a remote folder, if that's more appropriate)
- Use a tool that can watch for changes in a local directory and reflect them on a remote directory

---

You can implement both these options with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/).

---

### Scheduling

To synchronize changes in a local directory to a remote directory, use the WinSCP [`synchronize` script command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize) from a batch file like:

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=c:\writable\path\to\synchronize.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "synchronize remote C:\local\path /remote/path" ^
    "exit"
```

And [schedule the batch file to be run frequently using Windows scheduler](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

If you do not want to keep a local copy of the images, just move them to the FTP server, instead of synchronizing them. For that, replace the

```
"synchronize remote C:\local\path /remote/path" ^
```

with the [`put -delete` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put) like:

```
"put -delete C:\local\path\* /remote/path/" ^
```

For details see also a guide to [automating file transfers (or synchronization) to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

---

### Watching for changes

Use ["Keep remote directory up to date" function](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date) of WinSCP.

It can be used both in command-line/console mode using the [`keepuptodate` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_keepuptodate), like:

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=c:\writable\path\to\synchronize.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "keepuptodate C:\local\path /remote/path" ^
    "exit"
```

Or in a [graphical/GUI mode](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_keepuptodate). You can launch the graphical mode in WinSCP GUI (after logging in) or from a command-line using the [`/keepuptodate` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#operations) like:

```
winscp.exe ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/ /keepuptodate C:\local\path /remote/path
```

---

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*